Could not decode `ChargeAssetTxPayment::asset_id`
This is my parachain, I am getting this error while doing transaction.
1002: Verification Error: Runtime error: Execution failed: Runtime panicked: Bad input data provided to validate_transaction: Could not decode `ChargeAssetTxPayment::asset_id`: unexpected first byte decoding Option : RuntimeApi, Execution failed: Runtime panicked: Bad input data provided to validate_transaction: Could not decode `ChargeAssetTxPayment::asset_id`:\n\tunexpected first byte decoding Option\n


Someone please tell me what is wrong here?
Github repo

I think the problem is that polkadot-js probably doesn't send a correctly encoded extrinsic.
You should change:
    pallet_transaction_payment::ChargeTransactionPayment<Runtime>,
    pallet_asset_tx_payment::ChargeAssetTxPayment<Runtime>,

To
    pallet_asset_tx_payment::ChargeAssetTxPayment<Runtime>,

As the docs of ChargeAssetTxPayment mention, passing None as asset_id will fall back to the normal ChargeTransactionPayment extension.
